# html5-respond.js not rendering CSS3 properties in IE7 and IE8

Tags: 7, theming

I am working on a drupal 7 website. I am using the zen theme as starter theme. But the html5-respond.js not functioning properly.

I have added border radius property for the boxes, but its not rendering in IE7,IE8. But the js is there and its calling properly.

Please advise me.

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IEMobile 7]><html class="iem7"  lang="en" dir="ltr"><![endif]-->
<!--[if lte IE 6]><html class="lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"  lang="en" dir="ltr"><![endif]-->
<!--[if (IE 7)&(!IEMobile)]><html class="lt-ie9 lt-ie8"  lang="en" dir="ltr"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]><html class="lt-ie9"  lang="en" dir="ltr"><![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 9)|(gt IEMobile 7)]><!--><html  lang="en" dir="ltr"
  xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
  xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/terms/"
  xmlns:foaf="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/"
  xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
  xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
  xmlns:sioc="http://rdfs.org/sioc/ns#"
  xmlns:sioct="http://rdfs.org/sioc/types#"
  xmlns:skos="http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"><!--<![endif]-->

<head profile="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml/vocab">
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta about="/files/clients/etihad/en/index" property="sioc:num_replies" content="0" datatype="xsd:integer" />

............

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="html5-respond.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
```

Comment: Is html5-respond.js actually in the root directory of your site?

Answer (score 1):

IE8 doesn't work on @import'ed stylesheets. but you can write query by this way

```
@ Media screen and (min-width: 980px)
{

  / * CSS Document * /

}
```

and also you must include css3-mediaqueries js

```
<! - Css3-mediaqueries.js for IE less than 9 ->
 <! - [If lt IE 9]>
 <script src="http://css3-mediaqueries-js.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/css3-mediaqueries.js"> </ script>
 <! [Endif] ->
```

see this http://westilian.com/ie7-and-ie8-support-for-css3-media-query/